# Avoid to browse a list multiple time with linq, with dynamic conditions (filter)

Tags: c#, linq, where-clause

I have a list with `Article`  objects.
Parameters for this object are

> Category, Description, Status, Class

The user can filter the list with the combinaison he wants. Only Description, or Category + Class, an so on.

So if the user choose a criterion i'll get an int >= 0, otherwise i'll get -1.

For example if he choose to filter with `Status` and `Category`, i'll get

> FilterCategory = x, FilterDescription = -1, FilterStatus = y, FilterClass = -1

My way to filter the list is the following:

```
if (FilterCategory != -1)
    list = list.Where(a => a.Category == FilterCategory);
if (FilterDescription != -1)
    list = list.Where(a => a.Description == FilterDescription);
if (FilterStatus != -1)
    list = list.Where(a => a.Status == FilterStatus);
if (FilterClass != -1)
    list = list.Where(a => a.Class == FilterClass);
```

In this way, i have to iterate the list 4 time, it's not efficient with a lot of items. I would browse the list once, and check the 4 condition in an unique where. But i don't know how to do that with the specific condition != -1.

Thank you

Comment: Linq is lazy, so you are not iterating the list 4 times with your code.  The iteration doesn't occur until you iterate it or use a Linq extension that has to iterate it like `Count` or `Max`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do a HUGE Where query moving all your conditions it a single `Where` by noticing that:

```
if (FilterCategory != -1)
    list = list.Where(a => a.Category == FilterCategory);
```

is equivalent to:

```
list = list.Where(a => FilterCategory == -1 || a.Category == FilterCategory);
```

Then the query is:

```
list = list.Where(a => (FilterCategory == -1 || a.Category == FilterCategory)
                    && (FilterDescription == -1 || a.Description == FilterDescription)
                    && (FilterStatus == -1 || a.Status == FilterStatus)
                    && (FilterClass == -1 || a.Class == FilterClass));
```

But I really doubt it will improve your enumeration performance.

Comment: Downvote: This will do nothing to improve performance; it will actually slow down your performance because checking for the `-1` will happen once per item instead of once before. **Your original solution which stacks `Where` invocations on top of each other is correct**, and will only iterate the list once because of LINQ's deferred execution (as @juharr's comment explains).

Answer (score 4):

As Juharr mentions in the comments, Linq will not evaluate your `.Where` right after calling it. Only when calling `ToList/ToArray/First/Single/foreach` will it evaluate the clause and it will automatically combine your filters.

Comment: What if I have a left join and I use DefaultIfEmpty?

Comment: Late evaluation. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.defaultifempty

Comment: Remarks
This method is implemented by using deferred execution. The immediate return value is an object that stores all the information that is required to perform the action.

Answer (score 1):

```
list = list.Where(a => (FilterCategory != -1 || a.Category == FilterCategory) && 
                                       (FilterDescription != -1 || a.Description == FilterDescription) &&
                                       (FilterStatus != -1 || a.Status == FilterStatus) &&
                                       (FilterClass != -1 || a.Class == FilterClass));
```