# How to apply multiple filter conditions (simultaneously) on a list?

Tags: c#, linq, generics, design-patterns, specification-pattern

I have following C# code with  `.Net 4.0` framework.  This is created after referring [The Specification Pattern - by Jeff Perrin](http://devlicio.us/blogs/jeff_perrin/archive/2006/12/13/the-specification-pattern.aspx)

In the `GetProducts()` the conditions to be used are defined (hard coded) inside the method. There is another method named `GetProductsBasedOnInputFilters()`. In this method the list of specifications are made as parameter to the method.

**QUESTION**

What is the best way to apply these filters on the list of products, in this method?

**Note**: I have tried applying the `FindAll` clause inside a `foreach` loop and adding the results in a `list`. But that logic is incorrect - only those items that satisfy ***all*** of the conditions need to be returned.

**Note**: The number of specifications in the productSpeifications list will vary based on user input

**Note**:  The Approach mentioned in "[Dynamically build LINQ filter for the Any() method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16227743/dynamically-build-linq-filter-for-the-any-method?lq=1)" seems useful. However I am not sure how to use this approach here since I am dealing with List of `specifications`; not `generic delegates`.

**Filter Methods**

```
public static class ProductFilterHelper
{
    public static List<Product> GetProducts(List<Product> list)
    {
        double priceLimit = 100;

        //FIRST::
        //List<Product> selectedList =  list.FindAll(new OnSaleSpecification().IsSatisfiedBy);

        //SECOND::
        //AndSpecification<Product> spec = new AndSpecification<Product>(new OnSaleSpecificationForProduct(), new PriceGreaterThanSpecificationForProduct(priceLimit));
        //List<Product> selectedList = list.FindAll(spec.IsSatisfiedBy); 


        //THIRD:
        List<Product> selectedList = list.FindAll(new OnSaleSpecificationForProduct()
                                                       .And(new PriceGreaterThanSpecificationForProduct(priceLimit))
                                                       .And(new PriceGreaterThan105())
                                                       .IsSatisfiedBy
                                                  );

        return selectedList;
    }

    public static List<Product> GetProductsBasedOnInputFilters(List<Product> productList, List<Specification<Product>> productSpeifications)
    {
        List<Product> selectedList = new List<Product>();

        foreach (Specification<Product> specification in productSpeifications)
        {
            List<Product> currentList = productList.FindAll(specification.IsSatisfiedBy);

            if (currentList != null && currentList.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (Product p in currentList)
                {
                    if (!selectedList.Contains(p))
                    {
                        selectedList.Add(p);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return selectedList;
    }        

}
```

**Client**

```
class Program
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        List<Product> list = new List<Product>();

        Product p1 = new Product(false, 99);
        Product p2 = new Product(true, 99);
        Product p3 = new Product(true, 101);
        Product p4 = new Product(true, 110);
        Product p5 = new Product(false, 110);

        list.Add(p1);
        list.Add(p2);
        list.Add(p3);
        list.Add(p4);
        list.Add(p5);

        double priceLimit = 100;

        List<Specification<Product>> specifications = new List<Specification<Product>>();
        specifications.Add(new OnSaleSpecificationForProduct());
        specifications.Add(new PriceGreaterThanSpecificationForProduct(priceLimit));
        specifications.Add(new PriceGreaterThan105());

        List<Product> selectedList = ProductFilterHelper.GetProductsBasedOnInputFilters(list, specifications);

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

}
```

**Abstract Specifications**

```
public abstract class Specification<T>
{
    public abstract bool IsSatisfiedBy(T obj);

    public AndSpecification<T> And(Specification<T> specification)
    {
        return new AndSpecification<T>(this, specification);
    }

    public OrSpecification<T> Or(Specification<T> specification)
    {
        return new OrSpecification<T>(this, specification);
    }

    public NotSpecification<T> Not(Specification<T> specification)
    {
        return new NotSpecification<T>(this, specification);
    }
}

public abstract class CompositeSpecification<T> : Specification<T>
{
    protected readonly Specification<T> _leftSide;
    protected readonly Specification<T> _rightSide;

    public CompositeSpecification(Specification<T> leftSide, Specification<T> rightSide)
    {
        _leftSide = leftSide;
        _rightSide = rightSide;
    }
}
```

**Generic Specifications**

```
public class AndSpecification<T> : CompositeSpecification<T>
{
    public AndSpecification(Specification<T> leftSide, Specification<T> rightSide)
        : base(leftSide, rightSide)
    {

    }

    public override bool IsSatisfiedBy(T obj)
    {
        return _leftSide.IsSatisfiedBy(obj) && _rightSide.IsSatisfiedBy(obj);
    }
}

public class OrSpecification<T> : CompositeSpecification<T>
{
    public OrSpecification(Specification<T> leftSide, Specification<T> rightSide)
        : base(leftSide, rightSide)
    {
    }

    public override bool IsSatisfiedBy(T obj)
    {
        return _leftSide.IsSatisfiedBy(obj) || _rightSide.IsSatisfiedBy(obj);
    }
}

public class NotSpecification<T> : CompositeSpecification<T>
{
    public NotSpecification(Specification<T> leftSide, Specification<T> rightSide)
        : base(leftSide, rightSide)
    {
    }

    public override bool IsSatisfiedBy(T obj)
    {
        return _leftSide.IsSatisfiedBy(obj) && !_rightSide.IsSatisfiedBy(obj);
    }
}
```

**Product Specifications**

```
public class OnSaleSpecificationForProduct : Specification<Product>
{
    public override bool IsSatisfiedBy(Product product)
    {
        return product.IsOnSale;
    }
}

public class PriceGreaterThanSpecificationForProduct : Specification<Product>
{
    private readonly double _price;
    public PriceGreaterThanSpecificationForProduct(double price)
    {
        _price = price;
    }

    public override bool IsSatisfiedBy(Product product)
    {
        return product.Price > _price;
    }
}

public class PriceGreaterThan105 : Specification<Product>
{

    public override bool IsSatisfiedBy(Product product)
    {
        return product.Price > 105;
    }
}
```

**Entity**

```
public class Product
{
    private bool _isOnSale;
    private double _price = 0.0;

    public Product(bool isOnSale)
        : this(isOnSale, 0.0)
    {
        _isOnSale = isOnSale;
    }

    public Product(double price)
        : this(false, price)
    {
        _price = price;
    }

    public Product(bool isOnSale, double price)
    {
        _price = price;
        _isOnSale = isOnSale;
    }

    public bool IsOnSale
    {
        get { return _isOnSale; }
    }

    public double Price
    {
        get { return _price; }
    }
}
```

**REFERENCES**

1. [The Specification Pattern - by Jeff Perrin](http://devlicio.us/blogs/jeff_perrin/archive/2006/12/13/the-specification-pattern.aspx)
2. [Fluent interfaces and Method Chaining in C#](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/640997/Fluent-interfaces-and-Method-Chaining-in-Csharp)
3. [Avoid to browse a list multiple time with linq, with dynamic conditions (filter)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14672889/avoid-to-browse-a-list-multiple-time-with-linq-with-dynamic-conditions-filter)
4. [Dynamically build LINQ filter for the Any() method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16227743/dynamically-build-linq-filter-for-the-any-method?lq=1)

Comment: Must items on the list meet *all* of the specifications or *any* of them? Also why not just do something [like this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16227811/119477)

Comment: @ConradFrix It should meet all of the specifications. The Approach mentioned in [Dynamically build LINQ filter for the Any() method?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16227743/dynamically-build-linq-filter-for-the-any-method) seems useful. However I am not sure how to use that here since I am dealing with List of `specifications`; not `generic delegates`.

Comment: UPDATE: Related Question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21406492/how-to-combine-conditions-dynamically

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do one of several things:

- Combine the filters by stacking `Where` invocations on top of each other, like in @Lijo's answer
- Check all specifications on each item:

  ```
  return productList
    .Where(p => specifications.All(ps => ps.IsSatisfiedBy(p))
    .ToList()
  ```
- Create a composite 'And' specification that accepts multiple children instead of just two:

  ```
  public class AndSpecification<T> : ISpecification<T>
  {
      private ISpecification<T>[] _components;

      public AndSpecification(ISpecification<T>[] components) 
      {
        _components = components;
      }

      public bool IsSatisfiedBy(T item) 
      {
        return components.All(c => c.IsSatisfiedBy(item));
      }
    }
  ```

Then you could do:

```
var allFiltersSpecification = new AndSpecification(specifications)
return productList.Where(allFiltersSpecification.IsSatisfiedBy);
```

Comment: Thanks.. I am planning to go with `All`.. My current code is `return productList.Where(p => productSpecifications.All(ps => ps.IsSatisfiedBy(p))).ToList();`

Answer (score 2):

Following code works... Suggestions are welcome.

```
 public static List<Product> GetProductsBasedOnInputFilters(List<Product> productList, List<Specification<Product>> productSpecifications)
 {
            IEnumerable<Product> selectedList = productList;
            foreach (Specification<Product> specification in productSpecifications)
            {
                selectedList = selectedList.Where(specification.IsSatisfiedBy);
            }
            return selectedList.ToList();
 }
```

It is worth to take a look at the following too..

1. [Expression Tree Basics](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/charlie/archive/2008/01/31/expression-tree-basics.aspx)
2. [Generating Dynamic Methods with Expression Trees in Visual Studio 2010](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2009/09/14/generating-dynamic-methods-with-expression-trees-in-visual-studio-2010.aspx)
3. [Dynamically Composing Expression Predicates](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx)
4. [How to combine conditions dynamically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21406492/how-to-combine-conditions-dynamically)